# Format SD card to EXT4 in Windows command line

Tags: windows, vbscript, ext4

For part of some application it is required to write a VBScript to format SD card to EXT4 fs. Application is running on Windows OS. I found that the `format` command in CMD can perform disk formatting but only to FAT*, NTFSm UDF and ReFS. Is there any other way to do formatting to EXT4, but through the command line interface and not by using any third party software.

Application is running on Windows and it is intended on creating SD cards for Linux devices.

Comment: No.  Without external software, Windows cannot create an EXT4 formatted partition.  Have a look at this answer over on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1002140/want-to-create-an-ext4-partition-from-windows-10

Comment: I understand, it there any other way to automatize process using third party software? From either VBScript or any other way?

Comment: Depends on the third party software - if it can be called/controlled from a command line then you should be able to use vbscript to control it although the interaction may be limited.